# Lambda and Streams

Tags: java, lambda

If I have a list with integer and only wants one method to print certain numbers from that list. How can I do that? My attempt so far:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(42, 3, 18, 16, 1, 1, 3, 9, 7, 6, 10,);
System.out.print("odd: ");
    Predicate<Integer> MyIntegers =  (n -> n % 2 != 0) ;     
    printSelected(MyIntegers, odd);

public static void printSelected(List<Integer> list, Predicate<Integer> predicate) {
     list.forEach(n  -> System.out.print(" " + n));
```

It prints out all the integers.

Comment: Of course it does. You're not doing a `filter()`, so your predicate isn't being used for anything.

Comment: delete sentence what in really is a comment for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the predicate for anything. You need a `filter(predicate)`

What you most likely want to do is

```
String odd = list.stream().filter(i -> i % 2 != 0).collect(Collectors.join(" "));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List<String> result = list.stream()
    .filter(//your lambda function that returns a bool based on some condition)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```